# ZK - running on google app engine gives a timeout

Tags: google-app-engine, zk

I have a test page with a list of 100 items.
When I scroll the list down every time this timeout error pops up.
Is there a fix for this in ZK?

There is nothing else special just a list with 100 test rows.

[image]

Comment: Please post screenshots inline - external links have a tendency to go dead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:

On [zk docs](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Installation_Guide/Setting_up_Servers/Google_App_Engine) it says to use:

```
    <zk>
    <!-- clustering environment -->
    <system-config>
        <disable-event-thread/>
        <ui-factory-class>org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.SerializableUiFactory</ui-factory-class>
    </system-config>

    <!-- GAE doesn't allow user's thread -->
    <client-config>
        <resend-delay>-1</resend-delay>
    </client-config>
</zk>
```

But when I comment this line out:

```
<disable-event-thread/>
```

The error goes away!

Answer (score 0):

I'll make an educated guess that this is because you're storing some state (maybe "what page is this user on") in memory and expecting it to be around on the next request. In App Engine, it won't be. There are at least 3 ways around this:

- Use memcache
- If the data's important, put it in the datastore
- If the data's small and non-confidential, send it down to the client and have the client send it back to the server on the next request. In this case, that seems like the correct solution.